# ADF - pipeline fails with error -payload is too large

Tags: rest, azure-blob-storage, payload

I have a pipeline that makes an API Call, writes resulting JSON to a blob storage, and loads this JSON file into a SQL DB. I am doing the API pull in batches using an Until loop to control data volume; loop is incremented by hours (largest I tried is 24 hours and smallest is 1 hour) till current datetime. I set watermark value to 2022-10-01, so pipeline takes a few hours to finish.

After about 20 or so iterations, pipeline starts to fail with this error
'The payload including configurations on activity/dataset/linked service is too large. Please check if you have settings with very large value and try to reduce its size.'

Upon checking file size in blob storage, I see that file from API Call is never larger than 1.2 MB. I even tried by pulling the data for 1 hour at a time. It still fails. I also saw a post where it was mentioned that EnablePartitionDiscovery option set to True might cause this issue, but for me it is already set to false.

I am not sure what the issue might be. Could someone please help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the condition that you gave in until activity

Comment: I'm also getting this error. We are passing in _larger_ payloads to the input side and not getting this error. In our activity the output part is not shown, leading me to think it's the output that's the issue. But the output is tiny for successful executions of this.

Answer (score 0):

> The payload including configurations on activity/dataSet/linked service is too large. Please check if you have settings with very large value and try to reduce its size.

As per MS document, Payload includes activity configuration, datasets, linked service configurations and system properties generated by activity type. The limit for this payload size is 896KB only.

[image]
Image Source: MS document on [Data Factory Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#data-factory-limits).

**Recommendation given by Microsoft to solve this:**

> You hit this limit likely because you pass in one or more large parameter values from either upstream activity output or external, especially if you pass actual data across activities in control flow. Check if you can reduce the size of large parameter values, or tune your pipeline logic to avoid passing such values across activities and handle it inside the activity instead.

Reference: **MS doc** on [troubleshoot ADF and Synapse pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/azure/data-factory/data-factory-troubleshoot-guide#payload-is-too-large)